# How to create a summation function and call it, by passing Int array in swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have created a function that performs summation of numbers, by accepting Int array and returning the sum of elements as integer value. Below is my code, which I checked to be logically correct, but I am getting error during runtime mentioning,'index out of range' in console and "

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Code:

```
import UIKit
var x=[Int]()
var i=0
func dosomething(y:[Int])->Int{

    for index in 0..<y.count{
        if index==0{
            x[index]=0
            x[index]=x[index]+y[index]
            i=x[index]
            }
        else{
            x[index]=x[index-1]+y[index]
           i=x[index]
        }
       }
    return i
}

dosomething(y:[1,2,3])
```

Comment: Why are both your methods the same name?

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the code

Comment: You can use `reduce` func as shown in the first answer. I also would recommend to use proper variable names, because `var555` and `var55` are very confusing.

Comment: Question you should ask yourself: How large is `var555`??

Comment: Can you explain your logic? I do not understand why summation of a set of numbers has such complicated logic.

Comment: You can't just assign value using subscript if array is not large enough, especially if it's empty like your `var555`. `var555[index2]=0` — is invalid code.

Comment: I am not getting you. Using subscripts, I am assigning value, and it is not empty, as I have called with three parameters

Comment: You can only `replace` value of array using subscript. Like, if you have elements with `n` elements you can only access using indexes from `0` to `n-1`. If your array is empty you can't do it at all. So you should either pre-populate array up to size you gonna need, or use [`append`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126937-append)

Comment: Minimum verifiable example would be ```var test: [Int] = []; test[0] = 1; // your crash```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get error because the `X` array is empty and you are trying to set value that doesn't exist. you should first create that value then change it to what you want, change your method in this way:

```
func dosomething(y:[Int])->Int{
    x = [Int]()
    for index in 0..<y.count{
        if index==0{
            x.append(0)
            x[index]=x[index]+y[index]
            i=x[index]
        }
        else{
            x.append(0)
            x[index]=x[index-1]+y[index]
            i=x[index]
        }
    }
    return i
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set `x[index]=0` right after `append`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 7):

You can do directly using high order functions like this

```
[1,2,3].reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw we can do that way, but like to know what went wrong with my code

Comment: @user28434 you right, your var555 is empty then you can't assign value using subscript like this var555[index2]=0